# Как установить CSS?

Tags: css

Или его не стоит устанавливать? Или же он уже установлен? У меня HTML установлен...

Comment: Почитайте основы, хотя бы тут http://htmlbook.ru/samcss
Или пишите вопросы в личку, контакты есть в профиле.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML - это язык разметки. Его нельзя установить или не устанавливать, он есть как данное. Аналогично и CSS.

С одной стороны для программиста (верстальщика) это средство создавать страницы, а созданы они могут быть в любом редакторе (от блокнота до супер мощных IDE).

С другой стороны они распознаются браузерами, т.е. по ним будет построен внешний вид сайта (можно провести аналогию с компилятором).

Согласно вышесказанному, вы можете установить редактор для HTML и CSS, чтобы писать сайты. А можете установить себе различные браузеры (IE, Opera, FF, Chrome), чтобы написанные вами (или кем-то еще) сайты просматривать. И все это можно заключить под значение слова "установил HTML, CSS".